# Magento 2 partial invoice generate

Tags: magento2

In magento2 I want to generate a partial invoice of the order. It first-time invoice is generated but when I try to generate an invoice a second time for the same order than `$order->canInvoice()` return false.

any once have an idea about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

My case is generate multiple invoice (Not apply for any items) for one order. (Partial capture)

You can follow this instruction 
https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-programmatically-create-invoice-in-magento2/

I fixed a little bit.

`$invoice = $this->_invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order, $itemsArray);` //HERE

```
 public function prepareInvoice(Order $order, array $qtys = [])
{
    $isQtysEmpty = empty($qtys);
    $invoice = $this->orderConverter->toInvoice($order);
    $totalQty = 0;
    $qtys = $this->prepareItemsQty($order, $qtys);
    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $orderItem) {
        if (!$this->_canInvoiceItem($orderItem, $qtys)) {
            continue;
        }
        $item = $this->orderConverter->itemToInvoiceItem($orderItem);
        if (isset($qtys[$orderItem->getId()])) {
            $qty = (double) $qtys[$orderItem->getId()];
        } elseif ($orderItem->isDummy()) {
            $qty = $orderItem->getQtyOrdered() ? $orderItem->getQtyOrdered() : 1;
        } elseif ($isQtysEmpty) {
            $qty = $orderItem->getQtyToInvoice();
        } else {
            $qty = 0;
        }
        $totalQty += $qty;
        $this->setInvoiceItemQuantity($item, $qty);
        $invoice->addItem($item);
    }
    $invoice->setTotalQty($totalQty);
    $invoice->collectTotals();
    $order->getInvoiceCollection()->addItem($invoice);
    return $invoice;
}
```

I'm not using all of function `prepareInvoice()`. So I only need

```
$invoice = $this->orderConverter->toInvoice($order);
$invoice->collectTotals();
```